# Printing a whole row of a mutlidimensional array

Tags: arrays, printing, multidimensional-array

I'm taking an AP Computer Science Class at school, and we were working with using 2D arrays as Matrices and multiplying them together. I had worked with two dimensional arrays in the past and before winter break this worked:

```
int[][] array = new int[2][2]
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
System.out.println(array[x]);
```

Which would result in the output being:

```
00
00
```

But now it just prints a memory location; I am using the latest version of JCreator Pro, I am not entirely sure what version the IDE is, but I do know something has changed during the break, now when I auto gen a Main class file there are additional comment lines. After discovering that my old method was no longer working I went back to one of my old projects and found them to still be working fine, I do not know how exactly JCreator works, it is possible that it still runs older files with an older IDE or something like that so that things don't break like this. Can anyone clarify if this is indeed a new change with a new version of either java or JCreator?

Comment: ...did my answer help at all?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that your answer just resulted in the memory locations being put into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[x]));
```

instead. Don't know what's up with why the old thing was working, unfortunately.

I would *guess* that something is wrong with your IDE.